# C++ How to get the menu options to return to top if choice is < 5

Tags: c++

I used a for loop for the first menu but i decided to add a secondary menu option to get rid of the clutter.

When i added the second menu the for loop screwed everything up so i removed it. I just want the program to be able to say "Number invalid, please enter a correct number" When the user enters a number not present on the menu list.

Heres the code...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{

    double mi, ki, F, C;
    double lbs, kg, ft, m;
    int choice, choice2 = 0;


    cout<<"              MENU ONE               " << endl;
    cout<<"*************************************" << endl;
    cout<<"|1.) Convert miles to kilometers    |" << endl;
    cout<<"|2.) Convert kilometers to miles    |" << endl;
    cout<<"|3.) Convert Fahrenheit to Celsius  |" << endl;
    cout<<"|4.) Convert Celsius to Fahrenheit  |" << endl;
    cout<<"|5.)      FOR MORE CONVERSIONS      |" << endl;
    cout<<"*************************************" << endl;
    cin>> choice;

    if (choice >= 1 && choice < 5){
    switch (choice)
    {
        case 1:
            cout<< "Now enter the amount of miles you wish to convert: " <<endl;
            cin>> mi;
            cout<< "The answer is: " << mi / 0.62137 <<" Kilometers" <<endl;
            break;

        case 2:
            cout<<"Now enter the amount of Kilometers you want to convert: " << endl;
            cin>> ki;
            cout<< "The answer is: " << ki * .62137 <<" Miles " <<endl;
            break;

        case 3:
            cout<<"Now enter the degree in Fahrenheit: " << endl;
            cin>>F;
            cout<< "The answer is: " << (F-32)/1.8 <<" degrees Celsius "<< endl;
            break;

        case 4:
            cout<<"Now enter the degree in Celsius: " << endl;
            cin>>C;
            cout<< "The answer is: " << (C*1.8)+32 <<" degress Fahrenheit "  << endl;
            break;


        }
    }

//********************************************************************************************************//

    else if (choice == 5)
    {
        cout<<"             MENU TWO            " << endl;
        cout<<"*********************************" << endl;
        cout<<"|1.) Convert Pounds to Kilograms|" << endl;
        cout<<"|2.) Convert Kilograms to Pounds|" << endl;
        cout<<"|3.) Convert Feet to Meters     |" << endl;
        cout<<"|4.) Convert Meters to Feet     |" << endl;
        cout<<"|********************************" << endl;
        cin>>choice2;
    }
        if (choice2 >= 1 && choice2 < 5){
        switch (choice2)
        {


        case 1:
            cout<<"Now enter the weight in pounds: " <<endl;
            cin>>lbs;
            cout<<"The answer is: " << lbs / 2.2046 <<" kilograms " << endl;
            break;

        case 2:
            cout<<"Now enter the weight in kilograms: " << endl;
            cin>>kg;
            cout<< "The answer is: " << kg * 2.2046 <<" pounds "<< endl;
            break;

        case 3:
            cout<<"Now enter the number of feet to be converted to 'M': " <<endl;
            cin>>ft;
            cout<<"The answer is: " << (ft / 3.20808) << " meters "<< endl;
            break;

        case 4:
            cout<<"Now enter the number of meters to be converted to 'FT': " <<endl;
            cin>>m;
            cout<<"The answer is: " << (m * 3.20808) << " feet "<< endl;
            break;

            return 0;

            }

        }


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add default to both of the the switch cases:

```
default:
  cout << "Invalid input..." ;
  break ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to put `switch (choice2)` inside the `else if` block (because choice2 is a local variable in that block - you cannot access it outside that block of statements; also it would have followed cases 1 through 4, which would mean the second menu being shown when not asked to). Then you can follow the `if` and `else if` statements with an `else` block that prints out the error message.

```
if (choice >=1 && choice < 5)
{
    switch (choice)
    // the switch
}
else if (choice == 5)
{
    // the second menu
    switch (choice2)
    {
        // switch...
    }
else {
    // print error message
}
```

Or you can just put everything inside a single `switch`.

Then, put everything back inside a loop (or use goto), and add a similar loop inside the choice == 5 case as well (if you want to make sure the user enters the correct number on the second menu). Use a bool for the condition of the loop; set it to true when the user enters something wrong and false otherwise.

```
bool repeat = false;
while (repeat)
{
    // ask the user to input a number
    switch (choice)
    {
    // cases 1 through 4 (omitted)
    // don't forget to set repeat to false for these cases
    case 5:
    // print second menu and input choice2
        switch (choice2)
        {
            // prompt the user to enter another number
            bool repeat2 = false;
            while (repeat2)
            {
            // cases 1 through 4
            default: // use the default case label for numbers that are not 1 to 4
            // print error message
            repeat2 = true;
            }
        }
        repeat = false;
    break;
    default: // use the default case label for numbers that are not 1 to 5
        // print error message
        repeat = true;
    }
}
```